# iOS7 music Album stack effect

Tags: ios7

[image: Itunes Radio Feautred Section]

Hey guys! I am looking to replicate the above view in my project, the effect is pretty cool, it's quite hard to put in words here, but basically when scrolled, the album stacks behind each album will also move in a parallax manner.

Also looking to replicate the stacking effect as well. All I can derive from the screen, is that apple just reposition the album art from the first image in several positions to create differentiation in the back covers. There is about 70 percent opacity with a white outline. Any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Comment: have you solved the problem?